# How many times has the letter "N" or its repeat(eg: "NNNNN") been found in a text file?

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I am given a file.txt (text file) with a string of data. Example contents:

```
abcabccabbabNababbababaaaNNcacbba                                                              
abacabababaaNNNbacabaaccabbacacab                                                   
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN                                                    
aaababababababacacacacccbababNbNa                                                     
abababbacababaaacccc
```

To find the number of distinct repeated patterns of "N" (repeated one or more times) that are present in the file using unix commands.

I am unsure on what commands to use even after trying a range of different commands.

```
$ grep -E -c "(N)+" file.txt
```

the output must be 6

Comment: You could translate everything that is not `N` into a linefeed with `tr`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
$ sed 's/[^N]\{1,\}/\n/g' file.txt | grep -c N
6
```

How it works:

- Replace all sequences of one or more non-N characters in the input with a newline.
  This turns strings like `abcabccabbabNababbababaaaNNcacbba` into

  N

  NN
- Count the number of lines with at least one N (Ignoring the empty lines).

---

Regular-expression free alternative:

```
$ tr -sc N ' ' < file.txt | wc -w
6
```

Uses `tr` to replace all runs of non-N characters with a single space, and counts the remaining words (Which are the N sequences). Might not even need the `-s` option.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I like your `tr` idea better, actually. It doesn't even need grep to work. `tr -sc N ' ' < file.txt | wc -w`

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU awk (well, just tested with gawk, mawk, busybox awk and awk version 20121220 and it seemed to work with all of them):

```
$ gawk -v RS="^$" -F"N+" '{print NF-1}' file
6
```

It reads in the whole file as a single record, uses regex `N+` as field separator and outputs the field count minus one. For other awks:

```
$ awk -v RS="" -F"N+" '{c+=NF-1}END{print c}' file
```

It reads in empty line separated blocks of records, counts and sums fields.

Comment: I think this needs gnu awk due to the `RS` setting.

Comment: @jotne Tested on GNU awk, mawk, awk version 20121220 and Busybox awk.

Comment: Ok, that's fine to know that RS="" works all over. If there is a blank line inn between the data, you will get multiple results.

Comment: Oh yeah, that is true. I'll fix that in a sec. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` that should work on most system.

```
awk -F'N+' '{a+=NF-1} END {print a}' file
6
```

It splits the line by one or more `N` and then count number of fields-1 pr line.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a text file, and you want to count the number times a sequence of letters of N appear, you can do:

```
awk '{a+=gsub(/N+/,"")}END{print a}' file
```

This, however, will distinguish sequences that are split over multiple lines. Example:

```
abcNNN
NNefg
```

If you want this to be counted as a single sequence, you should do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=OFS=""}{$1=$1}{a+=gsub(/N+/,"")}END{print a}' file
```